# Adding a suffix in the tooltip of a heatmap using highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, heatmap

for a highcharts that is of a bar graph or someother graph it is possible to a suffix to our tooltip but in my case i need to add a tooltip to a map upon hover of it(like a '$' or '%' sign).Please provide a solution.
Below is the screen shot of the heatmap[image]

Comment: You can edit the tooltip format by [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#tooltip.formatter) or [pointFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#tooltip.pointFormat)

Comment: Yeah it can be done in normal graphs(i have implemented it ) but i am not getting how to do in case of maps

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live there it does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just as easy to do in maps vs. any other type of Highcharts graph.

Here's an example from a world map I recently constructed:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<span style="font-size: 14px;">' + this.point.name + '<br /><strong>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.value, 2) + '%</strong></span>';
        }
    }
```

In this example, I'm adding a percent sign as the suffix to my point value (which I also formatted to show values to two decimal points [such as 2.15]).